# Missing operand error in Ada

Tags: ada

When compiling this code written in Ada programming language, the next message appears: `missing operand in deg:=degree();`.  *Why* and *how* to resolve this issue?

```
With Ada.Text_IO; Use Ada.Text_IO;
With Ada.Integer_Text_IO; Use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
With Ada.Strings.Unbounded; Use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;

procedure polynomial is

    -- constructs a new polynomial term of the form a * x^b:
    function Polynomial(a,b : Integer) return Integer is
        type coef is array(Integer range <>)of Integer;
        type deg is new Integer;
        type c is new Integer;
    begin
        coef:=new int(b+1);
        coef(b):=a;
        deg:=degree(); --missing operand
        return a;
    end Polynomial;
```

Comment: See `Ada.Numerics`, for [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/groots).

Comment: This question changed a lot. Now it looks like an acceptable one. I wonder where the `degrees` function comes from. Probably it expects an argument. The c variable is not used.

Comment: Hi, this is the function related to degree:    function Polynomial(degree: Integer) return Integer is 
     
      type i is, d is new Integer;
      --int i,d=0;
      HOW TO WRITE THE NEXT LINES INTO ADA? 
   begin
     
        for(i=0;i<coef.length;i=i+1)
            if(coef[i]!=0)
                d=i;
   
      null;
   end Polynomial;

Answer (score 6):

Ada does not accept empty parameter lists. If a function does not accept parameters, omit the parameter list altogether.

```
deg:=degree;
```